# Are acids and bases always aqueous?

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, aqueous-solution

I am tying to determine if an acid is a liquid or aqueous solution? Please can some one enlighten me?

Answer (score 2):

There are varying definitions of"acid" (or "base") depending on solvent system; some do not involve water at all. For example, there are [Brønsted–Lowry acids (proton donors) and Lewis acids (electron acceptors)](http://www.personal.psu.edu/the1/acidbase.htm), though the [Arrhenius definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid%E2%80%93base_reaction#Arrhenius_definition) *is* based on *aqueous* solutions dissociating into $\ce{H+}$ (acid) or $\ce{OH-}$ (base) ions.

Of course, many acids are *not* liquids, such as solid [citric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citric_acid), which may be anhydrous or the monohdrate.